# Python 3 readline not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello so i am trying to read lines from a txt file. 
My code is the following:

```
import sys
accFiletypes = '.txt'
f = None
filnavn = None
correctFiletype = False

while (correctFiletype == False):
    filnavn = input("Filename (Type exit to leave):")
    if (filnavn.endswith(accFiletypes) == True):
        try:
            f = open(filnavn, 'r')
            correctFiletype = True  
            print("File successfully opened!")
        except IOError:
            print("File is not existing")
    elif (filnavn == "exit"):
        sys.exit("Program closed")
    else:
        print("Accepted filetypes: " + accFiletypes)

line = f.readline
print(line())
print(line(2))
print(line(3))
print(line(4))
print(line(5))
print(line(6))


f.close()
```

This prints the following:

```
Filename (Type exit to leave):test.txt
File successfully opened!
0000    00000000

00
00
0000
1

0000    0
```

The first 10 lines in "test.txt"

```
0000    00000000
0000    00001
0000    00001111
0000    000099
0000    00009999
0000    0000w
0000    5927499
0000    634252
0000    6911703
0000    701068
```

I want it to print out the lines in the txt file but i prints something completely different. What do i do?

Comment: did you forgot to put () after readline?

Comment: @Ezio No they just renamed it to `line`. @M3ME5 Don't pass numbers as argument, just call `line()` without arguments (but actually, use quamrana's solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `readline` does not take an argument, it just gets the "next" line. [See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). What you want to test is:

```
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())
```

However, I would suggest to work with `with()` which also handles closing the stream.

```
import sys
accFiletypes = '.txt'

def parse_file(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
          print(line)

correctFiletype = False
while (correctFiletype == False):
    filnavn = input("Filename (Type exit to leave):")
    if filnavn.endswith(accFiletypes):
        try:
            parse_file(filnavn)
            correctFiletype = True  
            print("File successfully opened!")
        except IOError:
            print("File is not existing")
    elif filnavn == "exit":
        sys.exit("Program closed")
    else:
        print("Accepted filetypes: " + accFiletypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
for line in f:
    print(line)

f.close()
```

Or, if you meant to read the first six lines you could have done:

```
line = f.readline
for _ in range(6):
    print(line())
```

Just to note that `line = f.readline` makes `line` a bound function and the expression `line()` is a call to `f.readline()`.